# Nifi docker image running locally but giving sensitive prop key error not found on Rancher pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, apache-nifi, kubernetes-helm, alpine-linux

I created an Alpine docker image for Nifi 1.14.0 and used that image in stateful-set yaml file for Nifi pods' deployment on Rancher. On running the image locally on my VM, it is running without any errors and generating the HTTPS URL for Nifi UI but when the same image is deployed on Rancher via helm through the stateful-set file, its logs give "nifi.sensitive.prop.key" not found error and "there was an issue decrypting protected properties". How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Set `NIFI_SENSITIVE_PROPS_KEY` environment variable. It should be atleast 12 characters. You can see more details how it is used in [this article](https://www.contemplatingdata.com/2017/08/28/apache-nifi-sensitive-properties-need-know/).

Comment: Thank you @Dakshinamurthy Karra. I'll try this.